# Compressing small files with gzip makes its size smaller than with bzip2, why?

Tags: linux, files, compression, gzip, bzip2

I have a question, just a little thing couch my eyes
it's about compression with gzip and bzip2:
If I understood correctly - bzip2 requires more processing power but compresses files smaller and more efficient than gzip.

When I tried to compress a 6MB file with bzip2 its size got smaller than with gzip as I expected.
But when I tried to compress a file with a size of 5 bytes with bzip2 its size got larger than with gzip.

`bzip2 5_bytes_file`

`du -b 5_bytes_file.bz2` result: 42 bytes

`gzip 5_bytes_file`

`du -b 5_bytes_file.gz`
result 38 bytes

Why is it happening? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you explain why this is surprising? These are two different formats, and maybe one has a slightly bigger header than the other; the "I compress files with less content than my header is long" problem is not really something you would ever need to optimize your compressor for.

Comment: I don't see an issue here. The two formats store their internal data structures differently, one requiring more space than the other. I wonder why you are attempting to compress a file that is five characters large?

Comment: @MarcusMüller [Some `gzip` implementations](https://man.openbsd.org/gzip) refuse to store the compressed file if it becomes larger than the original, arguable implementing such an "optimization" :-)  Although a file could become larger by compression for other reasons too, such as when it contains truly random data.

Comment: I closed this one now that you asked on [so]. For future reference, this is actually borderline and probably on topic here as well. But you're more likely to get answers on SO and since you've already posted there, we might as well close this one.

Comment: @Kusalananda well, you can hardly entropy-reduce a 5 byte string, so I'd guess that bz2 might do the same, albeit maybe a bit shuffled.